# Проблема с распараллеливанием программы с помощью OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, распараллеливание, openmp

У меня есть программа работающая с массивами и на выходе выдающая одно число.  Для распараллеливания программы я использую OpenMP, но проблема в том, что после написания директив, я начал получать ответы не схожие с ответами программы без распараллеливания. Кто-нибудь может подсказать где я допустил ошибку?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

#define LOOP_COUNT 100
#define MIN_1_ARRAY_VALUE 1
#define MAX_1_ARRAY_VALUE 10
#define MIN_2_ARRAY_VALUE 10
#define MAX_2_ARRAY_VALUE 100
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433
#define thread_count 4

double generate_random(unsigned int* seed, int min, int max) {
    return (double)((rand_r(seed) % 10) + (1.0 / (rand_r(seed) % (max - min + 1))));
}
double map_1(double value) {
    return pow(value / PI, 3);
}
double map_2(double value) {
    return fabs(tan(value));
}
void dwarf_sort(int n, double mass[]) {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    while (i < n) {
        if (mass[i-1]<mass[i]) {
            i = j;
            j = j + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            double tmp = mass[i];
            mass[i] = mass[i - 1];
            mass[i - 1] = tmp;
            --i;
            if (i==0)
            {
                i = j;
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("lab work 3 in processing...!\n");

    int trial_counter;
    int array_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    struct timeval before, after;
    long time_diff;
    gettimeofday(&before, NULL);

    for (trial_counter = 0; trial_counter < LOOP_COUNT; trial_counter++) {
        double arr1[array_size];
        double arr2[array_size / 2];
        double arr2_copy[array_size / 2];
        double arr2_min = DBL_MAX;
        unsigned int tempValue = trial_counter;
        unsigned int *currentSeed = &tempValue;
        //stage 1 - init

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count)
        {

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr1, currentSeed, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
                arr1[i] = generate_random(currentSeed, MIN_1_ARRAY_VALUE, MAX_1_ARRAY_VALUE);
                // printf("arr[%d] = %f\n", i, arr1[i]);
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr2, arr2_copy, array_size, currentSeed, arr2_min) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
                double value = generate_random(currentSeed, MIN_2_ARRAY_VALUE, MAX_2_ARRAY_VALUE);
                arr2[i] = value;
                arr2_copy[i] = value;
                if (value < arr2_min) {
                    arr2_min = value;
                }
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr1, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
                arr1[i] = map_1(arr1[i]);
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr2, arr2_copy, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 1; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
#pragma omp critical
                arr2[i] = map_2(arr2_copy[i] + arr2_copy[i - 1]); //Возможно -
            }
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(arr2, arr1, array_size) schedule(guided, thread_count)
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
                arr2[i] = pow(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
            }
#pragma omp parallel sections
            {
#pragma omp section
                {
                    dwarf_sort((int) array_size / 2, arr2);
                }
            }
            double final_sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array_size / 2; i++) {
                if (((int) arr2[i]) / 2 == 0) {
                    final_sum += sin(arr2[i]);
                }
            }
            // printf("Iteration %d, value: %f\n", trial_counter, final_sum);
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&after, NULL); /* запомнить текущее время T2 */
    time_diff = 1000 * (after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) + (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec) / 1000;
    printf("\nN=%d. Milliseconds passed: %ld\n", array_size, time_diff);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы используете генератор случайных чисел `rand_r` с фиксированным начальным seed-ом. Эта функция ре-ентерабельна, но последовательность вызовов (для заполнения разных частей arr1) отличается в однопоточном и многопоточном варианте. Кроме того, вы используете общую переменную tempValue, передаваемую через указатель, которая используется генератором случайных чисел для чтения и записи. Поэтому, arr1 будет заполнен другими значениями, что уже может повлиять на ответ.
2. Вы не синхронизируете чтение/запись при обращении к переменной arr2_min, объявленной как shared.

```
                if (value < arr2_min) {
                    arr2_min = value;
                }
```

Поэтому, даже если отдельные обращения к double будут атомарны для вашего процессора, все равно, посе 2-го цикла arr2_min не обязательно будет содержать минимум массива arr2.

Дальше не смотрел...